# DNS resolution between GCE projects over VPN

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have two GCE projects that are connected using a GCE Site to site VPN, i need to share DNS across the two projects is there a simple way of doing this?

cheers
D

Comment: What do you mean by share DNS? is it the Google Cloud DNS? Can you provide more details about your use case?

Comment: yes google cloud DNS, basically i want resources in each project to be able to resolve in the other projects over the vpn

Comment: Did you try assigning service accounts between your projects? You can use service accounts to access the Cloud DNS.